# PHP get PID of system() command

Tags: php, unix

I'm trying to find the PID of a background system call I'm making from a php webpage. If I call 'ps -A' from within the PHP script and print it to my browser, it doesn't have the same output as calling 'ps -A' from my terminal. This is particularly frustrating because I can see the PID of the background process that PHP called from my terminal, but not from within PHP.

In other words, my code looks like this:

```
system("process &");
system("ps -A");
```

But that doesn't produce the same output as calling 'ps -A' from the terminal. Not only that, but 'process' shows up in terminal, but not from the PHP call.

Can anybody explain to me why this is and how I could get the PID of 'process' from within my PHP code? (For the record, I've also tried using variations of the code including using exec() and passthru(), none of which have worked so far.)

Thanks.

Comment: One option is to use [proc_open and proc_get_status](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4731666/82769)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo $!
```

will get the PID of the last command, so..

```
system("process & echo $!");
```

Comment: That suggestion sounded like it might work, but it didn't. Instead, it started printing an error that it could not open the file it was supposed to be opening ('process' takes input from a file and redirects output to a file). It was not producing this error with any of my other attempts.

Comment: well if it takes arguments, did you pass them? just replace the second system call with "echo $!" and leave the first as before

Comment: I did pass the arguments. I just tried calling them separately (right now it's exec("process &"); system ("echo $!") ), and nothing is printing out from the system(echo) call. Why would that be?

Comment: For the record, the reason I'm doing this is because I need the PHP script to wait until after the background process is done to move forward; the reason I don't call 'process' in the foreground is because then the server gets hung up and becomes unresponsive to other requests (which doesn't happen when it's in the background).

If there's an easier way to accomplish this, then I'm open to suggestions.