# Get pid from php pclose_popen(exec) on windows

Tags: java, php, windows, cmd

I have script 
`pclose(popen("D: & cd D:\server\LoginServer & start /b startLoginServer.bat", "r"));`
`startloginserver.bat` starts java process and i need to get its pid to kill it when needed.
I'm new in these things.

Comment: You could use [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) and [proc_close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-close.php) instead and then use [proc_get_status](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-get-status.php) to get the pid

Comment: Check out the solution in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731637/killing-processes-opened-with-popen

Answer (score 0):

In cmd to do it there's a command `tasklist` .. will list the process with **pid** and then type `taskkill /PID pid /F` .
Note: pid is the listed process id

Comment: Is there any way to get pid after running exec or not? I mean to get pid when php finishes his work.