# How to run (and kill) headless browser via cron job for automated scraping in PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping, headless-browser

I've been attempting to create a spider that will run via cron every morning.  I wanted to incorporate a headless browser in order to get the rendered DOM (after javascript).

I tried using [Crowbar](http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Crowbar) (a headless browser) and have had success getting one (and only one) page via cURL with it.  Documentation is non-existent, and it hangs after every first request.

How can I kill Crowbar's process via PHP, in essence to be able to start/stop it at will.  Or do people just leave these headless browsers running constantly?  That seems like a resource drain.

This is the code I've tried, but killing the process does not work.

```
$toExecute = "\"" .ROOT . "/vendors/xulrunner/xulrunner.exe \" \"". ROOT . "/app/Vendor/crowbar/xulapp/application.ini \" 2>&1 &";
$handle = shell_exec($toExecute);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://127.0.0.1:10000/?url=' . $url . '&delay=3000&view=as-is');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$html = curl_exec ($curl);

exec("kill -KILL ".$handle); //this does not work...
echo $html;
```

Or is there a better way to scrape in php with javascript?  I'd love to hear it...

Comment: curl handles in PHP have absolutely **NOTHING** to do with killable processes. curl will be running purely inside php. there will be no external process to kill.

Comment: I'm not attempting to 'kill a cURL process' - I'm attempting to kill crowbar  (the process started on line 2 of the above code).

Comment: If you use `proc_open()`, you can later call `posix_kill()` http://stackoverflow.com/a/4731666/82769

Comment: I'm having issues getting `proc_open()` to run on windows.  The command that works fine in `popen()` (xulrunner.exe) isn't finding the application.ini file to run in `proc_open()`, despite using an absolute path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shell_exec()` does not return a handle. It returns the output of a command. So, you'd see STDOUT and STDERR in `$handle`. I would stop this and instead only echo `$!`, which will be set as PID of the last executed command. This PID you can then pass to `kill` to properly kill `xulrunner.exe`

So, to sum it up:

```
$toExecute = "<path>/xulrunner.exe <params> >/dev/null 2>/dev/null & echo $!";
$myPid = shell_exec( $toExecute );

...

exec( "/bin/kill $myPid" );
```

Note that for safety you should use `escapeshellarg()` and `escapeshellcmd()` where appropriate. Otherwise you are exposing yourself to shenanigans.

Comment: I'm in a windows environment (Apache) and though this is a step in the right direction, I've been unable to get the process to run in the background with shell_exec and also echo the process id. (I've tried everything under the sun to get the process to run in the background, but on windows, it's been a nightmare)

Comment: For posterity, I believe Aleksi's information is correct, but for the sake of scraping, I ended up switching from Crowbar to PhantomJS.  PhantomJS is a simple include and can be stopped from inside itself quite easily by calling `phantom.exit()` at the end of the script - which completely took care of the issue for me.