# PHP pid from popen

Tags: php

Do I have a chance to find the pid of the application I'm running with `popen`?

I know it's possible with `proc_open` but it's unlikely for me to change my app's structure

Or how can I stop the process that is opened with `popen` and continues to run?

When encoding stream with ffmpeg sometimes I need to stop

Comment: No, you can't get it from `popen()`.

Comment: If you need that level of control, you need to use the lower-level functions.

Answer (score 0):

function popen:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php

function pclose:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pclose.php

Where pclose will return -1 if it could not close the process.

If pclose cannot close the process run popen & use a system command to kill the process by getting the parent pid of the forked process:

[Killing processes opened with popen()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731637/killing-processes-opened-with-popen)

Very last answer may work, otherwise use proc_open:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php